# Cant get rails ActiveRecord :condifions working, 'wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following code for an active record condition in a controller

```
 @this_section = Section.all( :conditions => [ "url_section = ?", params[:ssection] ] )
```

And when I try to goto to the webpage associated with it I get the following error in the browser:

```
ArgumentError in UpcomingEventsController#index

wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

And in the puma log I am getting:

```
 Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-21 11:06:22 +0000
 Processing by UpcomingEventsController#index as HTML
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

 ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):

 app/controllers/upcoming_events_controller.rb:11:in `index'
```

11 is the line of code at the top of this post

I was using  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html to work out how to do it.

The route for this page is

```
   get 'upcoming_events/:ssection/:cost', to: 'upcoming_events#index'
```

What I am trying to do is set @this_section to the record from the sections table of the database WHERE url_section = params[:ssection].  I am using rails 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to apply 2.3 query syntax to ActiveRecord 5.x. The proper way is:

```
@this_section = Section.where(url_section: params[:section])
```

or probably more accurately (since you seem to need only one instance in this case):

```
@this_section = Section.find_by(url_section: params[:section])
```